relationship between eigenvalues and determinant 0
I have a question about the determinant condition used to find eigenvalues:
Why does the determinant det(A−λI) need to equal 0 when solving for eigenvalues? My understanding is that when the determinant is 0, it implies the matrix is singular and does not have a full rank.
Does this mean the dimensions shift to a lower subspace (or previous dimensions)?
Is there a specific relationship between eigenvalues and this shift in dimensions?

Any insights would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

What's does "the dimensions shift to a lower subspace (or previous dimensions)" mean?

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of an $n\times n$ matrix $A,$ then there is a nonzero vector $x$ such that $Ax=\lambda x,$ so $Ax=\lambda Ix$ (where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix), so $Ax-\lambda Ix$ is the zero vector, so $(A-\lambda I)x$ is the zero vector, so $A-\lambda I$ is singular, and so $\det(A-\lambda I)=0.$

The condition $det(A−\lambda I)=0$ when solving for eigenvalues arises because of the fundamental nature of linear transformations and their effect on vectors in a vector space.
An eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a matrix $A$ corresponds to a scalar such that there exists a non-zero vector $v$ (the eigenvector) for which the transformation $A$ acts as simple scaling on $v$. Mathematically, this is expressed as: $$ Av=\lambda v. $$ In other words, $A$ is a linear transformation such that when applied on the eigenvectors $v$, those vectors are only scaled by a factor $\lambda$ (there is no change in direction or position).
Rearranging this gives:
$$(A−\lambda I)v=0$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. The above equation states that $v$ lies in the null space (or kernel) of the matrix $A-\lambda I$.
The determinant of a square matrix tells us whether the matrix is invertible (non-singular) or not.
Now, if $det(A-\lambda I)\neq0$, the matrix $A-\lambda I$ is invertible, and the only solution to $Av=\lambda v$ is the trivial solution $v=0$. So if your determinant is non-null there are no eigenvectors (we say that these vectors that are invariant up to scale under the transformation $A$).
Conversely, if $det(A-\lambda I)=0$, the matrix $A-\lambda I$ is singular, meaning it has a non-trivial null space: there exist non-zero eigenvectors. The eigenvalues $\lambda$ simply capture how the transformation scales (stretches or compresses) vectors along a specific direction (the direction of $v$).
In a nutshell, The condition $det(A−\lambda I)=0$ ensures that $A−\lambda I$ has a non-trivial null space. This is a necessary condition for the existence of non-trivial eigenvectors that remain invariant up to scaling under the transformation $A$.

You could format \det

$\det(A)$ looks better than $det(A)$.
